# Bootstrap open anchor by external link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

following problem

I'm using from startbootstrap the freelancer template: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/

Now I want to to have a specific link from my index.html(Page 1) to one of the specific portfolio items on another page (Page 2).

My problem, I can link to Page 2 by simply using the  tag and that works but I want that directly when the user is using the link the right portfolio item. I just tried to do  but the window is not opening but without the #portfoliomodal1, I'm just getting redirected to page 2.

Any ideas ?

Edit: 
The link code `<a data-toggle="modal" href="#area1" class="portfolio-link list-group-item">Area1</a>`

The Code of Page 2

```
      <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="area1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="kopf" class="container-fluid shadow-bottom">
     <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="logobild" src="images/colums/WagnerLOGO_SW.png"></a>
     </div>
     </div>
        <div id="tissot" class="banner_uhrenpage">
           <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
              <div class="lr">
                 <div class="rl">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                 <article class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <h2>Tissot</h2>
                    <hr class="star-primary">
                 </article>
              </div>
              <section id="ausstellung" class="row">
                 <article class="col-md-12 auscon links">
                    <img id="ausstellungsbild" src="images/Markenspiegel/Tissot/Stimmungsbild.jpg" width="100%">
                 </article>
              </section>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
           <section id="ausstellung" class="row">
              <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 auscon ausstellungnorm links">
                 <img src="images/Markenspiegel/Tissot/Uhr1.jpg">
              </article>
           </section>
           <hr class="divider">
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Short answer: Don't use a one page template for a multi-page site. The portfolio items were designed to be used on the one page with their info in a modal. Not on another page.

Comment: I'm not using the whole template, just this special technique with the anchor, but I got this idea from this template

Comment: Can you add your tried code or any fiddle